# How do you right rotate a binary search tree in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, rotation, binary-search-tree

I've seen a bunch of stuff about AVL trees and how to rotate them, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm trying to rotate a binary search tree to the right (a diagram is included below). Like I have a specific node I want to rotate around and I'm confused on how to rotate to the right around it.

If I start with a function like
`void rotateRight(int key){}`, how would I use the value inside each of the nodes to then rotate the tree around it.

[image]

Comment: It's important to show your code when asking a question about it. There's very little difference between right-rotating a tree, whether it's a plain old binary tree, a BST, an AVL tree, a red-black tree or whatever. Fundamentally, you need to know the node that's being rotated, and you need to be aware that after rotation, the tree will have a new root. At the minimum, I'd say this function should return a pointer to the new root.

Comment: Have you tried doing it with paper and pencil? That is usually the best first step when writing a tree function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.